# Import data from Excel file to SQL Server database

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I want to import data from Excel file to SQL Server database using Laravel but I have this error

> {
> SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]La conversion d'un type de données nvarchar en type de données datetime a créé une valeur hors limites. (SQL: insert into [users] ([name], [email], [password], [updated_at], [created_at])
> }

NB: when I import the same file to a MySQL table with same atrributes its OK. But when I want to do the same thing into SQL Server database I get error message

```
(userimport)    
    <?php
        
        namespace App\Imports;
        
        use App\Models\User;
        use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
        use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
        use Hash;
        
        class UserImport implements ToModel,WithHeadingRow
        {
            /**
            * @param array $row
            *
            * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
            */
           
        
        
            public function model(array $row)
            {
                return new User([
                    'name' => $row['name'],
                    'email' => $row['email'], 
                    'password' => Hash::make('password')
                ]);
            }
        
        }
       
    
    
    ----------
    
    
    (Controller)
         public function import(Request $request)
            {
                //$file = $request->file('file');
                
                Excel::import(new UserImport,$request->file);
        
                //Excel::import(new UserImport,request()->file('file'));
                   
                
            }
      
    
    
    ----------
    
    
    (model)
         protected $fillable = [
                'name',
                'email',
                'password',
            ];




that's my code source from 3 classes(model,controller,Userimport)
```

Comment: The *entirety* of your question should be in English; that includes error messages. Many of us won't understand what that error says, which means we can't help you.

Comment: I don't see `[updated_at], [created_at]` in your code. The error concerns a conversion to datetime, so these are probably important

Comment: Yes i dont have [updated_at], [created_at]  in my code cause its automaticcaly added by sql server (date système) ... thats why i don't understand the problème

Comment: Just reposted the same question from yesterday! And apparently you deleted the old one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Laravel is, but if you are using Excel and SQL Server, you can leverage some VBA code to do the lift.

```
Sub InsertInto()

'Declare some variables
Dim cnn As adodb.Connection
Dim cmd As adodb.Command
Dim strSQL As String

'Create a new Connection object
Set cnn = New adodb.Connection

'Set the connection string
cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=your_database_name;Data Source=your_server_name"


'Create a new Command object
Set cmd = New adodb.Command

'Open the Connection to the database
cnn.Open

'Associate the command with the connection
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn

'Tell the Command we are giving it a bit of SQL to run, not a stored procedure
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

'Create the SQL
strSQL = "UPDATE TBL SET JOIN_DT = '2013-01-22' WHERE EMPID = 2"

'Pass the SQL to the Command object
cmd.CommandText = strSQL


'Execute the bit of SQL to update the database
cmd.Execute

'Close the connection again
cnn.Close

'Remove the objects
Set cmd = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Finally, set the appropriate reference.

[image]